# Can not get a WSDL maximum number of redirects(5) reached?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

we implemented one jax-ws webservice using RPC style and published using the following url

```
http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl
```

but when we issue the

```
wsimport -keep http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl
```

command to generate the stub from the jdk bin command prompt wsimport throwing Can not get a WSDL maximum number of redirects(5) reached,

Comment: Most likely it is unable to reach the WSDL due to a proxy issue.

Comment: but it is opening in browser,and wsdl is there in local system only.....

Comment: Did u try with ur local ip address.  if you have no objection, share the WSDL here.

Comment: Thanks for reply,i got sir,windows cmd interface uses IE proxy by default..

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help